# most 2 common values based on other column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
Team | Player
Barca | Messi
Chelsea | Lampard
Barca | Messi
Barca | Messi
Chelsea | Lampard
Chelsea | Drogba
Barca | Iniesta
Barca | Xavi
Barca | Iniesta
Barca | Puyol
```

So I need a query that retrieves the top two common players in each team. something like this:

```
Team | Player
Barca | Messi
Barca | Iniesta
Chelsea | Lampard
Chelsea | Drogba
```

Comment: Team `Barca` has more than two, you just need the top two?

Comment: yes exactly only the top two

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a subquery/CTE to calculate the counts of each player and the ranking, by numbering rows according to descending order of count per team.  Then pull out the top two players from each team:

**Query** ([**demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/21711/12)):

```
with ranks as (
  select
    team, player, count(*) as count,
    row_number() over (partition by team order by count(*) desc) as teamrank
  from players p
  group by team, player
)
select
  team, player
from
  ranks
where teamrank <= 2
order by team, teamrank
```

**Results**:

```
|    TEAM |  PLAYER |
---------------------
|   Barca |   Messi |
|   Barca | Iniesta |
| Chelsea | Lampard |
| Chelsea |  Drogba |
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a place where you want window functions:

```
select team, player
from (select team, player, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by team order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from team_player tp
      group by team, player
     ) tp
where seqnum in (1, 2)
```

Note that this nests the aggregation function `count(*)` within the windows function.

Comment: I fixed it.  Howeveer, Mellamokb beat me to the answer by about 40 seconds, alas.

Comment: It is amazing how remarkably similar our queries are.  Guess we think alike :)